# espresso onData matches multiple views in the hierarchy?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm testing an app using espresso. This app has 2 ListViews, espresso **onData** function finds the two ListViews but they have different ids.

code:

```
onData(withId(R.id.order_jijia_listview)).perform(ViewActions.click());
```

result:

```
ListView{id=2131493579, res-name=order_jijia_listview, visibility=VISIBLE, width=768,
            height=659, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, 
            is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, 
            is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false,
            has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=345.0, child-count=7} ****MATCHES****

ListView{id=2131493586, res-name=order_jijia_pop_listview, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0,
            height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, 
            is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, 
            is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, 
            has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second ListView is not marked as `****MATCHES****`, so the problem is not there.

You should use `onData` only for ListView elements, not for the `ListView` itself.
To find ListView you need to use `onView`:

```
onView(withId(R.id.order_jijia_listview)).perform(ViewActions.click());
```

What do you want to achieve? Click on the list element?
Thus you need to use `onData` with complex matcher as:

```
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is("Americano"))).perform(click());
```

You can read more about `onData` and `onView` in [official espresso tutorial](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/basics/index.html).